# warning generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/InitialConfigSource/Proxy.php

Tags: magento2

This is killing me.

When I run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` it throws this:

> Warning:
>   include(/vendor/composer/../../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/InitialConfigSource/Proxy.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

And when I run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` it throws this:

`Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist`

Site was running perfectly. I had run `setup:upgrade` before without any problem. I had also ran `di:compile`.

But today, all of sudden this is happening.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I used to follow this every time when I compile:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/deployment-flow.html

Could it be the reason now that I cannot run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` or `bin/magento setup:di:compile`?

I remember, at first running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` it threw error, after that I am stuck, couldn't run any CLI commands.

**UPDATE 2**

On first run `setup:upgrade`, it threw an error. Unfortunately I did not make a note of that and re-run the `setup:upgrade` again. Since then the above-mentioned error is thrown.

**UPDATE 3**

Alright, so in my local instance, I was able to reproduce a similar error. It's slightly different than what I was getting in my live server:

> Warning:
>   include(/vendor/composer/../../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

So, after I ran `composer update` It did allow me to run `Magento CLI commands`. And I was able to compile.

**I still want to understand this. I am yet to perform this into my live server.**

Comment: Check permissions

Comment: Permissions are ok. No permissions were changed.

Comment: i think here is a solution you look for https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251709/88489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use dockergento try

```
dockergento composer dump-autoload
```

```
 docker exec -it -u 0 hp_redis_1 bash
```

Then inside

```
redis-cli flushall
exit
```

and then run setup:upgrade . 
If you don't use dockergento it might be something similar for bin magento.
first try bin/magento composer dump-autoload.

Comment: What are the autoloads? Is it safe to dump them?

Comment: just have exactly the same error https://i.imgur.com/JAwvpHJ.png
it Generated autoload files containing 631 classes
https://i.imgur.com/mf90Nst.png
fixed.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly did you do to run into this error? I want to understand what triggers this error.

Comment: Sure can. I run ```dockergento composer install --no-suggest -o --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist```
and it updated some modules.

Comment: If it fixes an error and you accept my answer I'm gonna bounty my question ... I am so stucked https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310097/tring-to-filter-products-with-value-id

Comment: So you are saying, `composer install` triggered this error?

Comment: Sure . In my case absolutely yes.

Comment: If it did the job accept it please and I'll have enough rep to set bounty on my question.

Comment: I am yet to perform this on my live server. It cost me a night before and had to revert from backup. I will perform this soon.

Comment: sure ! let me know the results. Don't you have staging server to test things there at first? you can install bitbucket pipelines and everything will be checked for errors , your webpage will never be in the same situation.

Comment: very nice answer. Thanks Giga

Answer (score 15):

I solved simply by composer:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to run update composer. Please follow the below command.

```
composer update

php bin/magento cache:flush and cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I know, like I said, I want to understand this. Why this happens, what are the causes?

Comment: Can you please let me know, your issue has been fixed using my solution or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are running composer or magento commands with root user (sudo), just fix the permissions and the owners of your magento files and directories (fix the generated directory and remove its content)

After fixing the owner [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions) is a good answer for the permissions

Comment: There is no permission issue. I am running command same way I have been running, that is from magento user.