# Triyng to filter products with value_id

Tags: magento2, product, database, filter

Tried filtering with `option_id` and `value_id` but it is looking for value and when I change it to `catalog_product_entity_int.value_id` or `at_manufacturer.value_id` it returns syntax error.

Trying to filter with code

```
$productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')->addFieldToFilter('something here',['eq'=>'value id or option_id here']);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6C7O.png

query looks like that when debugging

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_manufacturer`.`value` AS `manufacturer` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_manufacturer` ON (`at_manufacturer`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_manufacturer`.`attribute_id` = '81') AND (`at_manufacturer`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (at_manufacturer.value = 'LG')
```

How to filter that properly?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: when I use manufacturer as a first argument it's not filtering right. when I use main_table.value_id it returns syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `LG`, you should provide it's `id`. I am not sure how you are using this collection but you should be able to do this if you know your `manufacturer option id`:

```
//collectionFactory = \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
$productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer')
   ->addFieldToFilter('manufacturer',['eq'=>'21']); //value
```

This create `sql` like this:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_manufacturer`.`value` AS `manufacturer` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_manufacturer` ON (`at_manufacturer`.`row_id` = `e`.`row_id`) AND (`at_manufacturer`.`attribute_id` = '81') AND (`at_manufacturer`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE ((at_manufacturer.value = '21')) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1)
```

Hope this helps.